# JavaFX MediaPlayer doesn't play MP4 video from JAR file

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I can't play mp4 video inside jar file.

This doesn't work `new Media("jar:file:/Users/me/my.jar!/video.mp4");`

But this works `new Media("file:/Users/me/video.mp4");`

But this also works although flv from Oracle http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv
`new Media("jar:file:/Users/me/my.jar!/oow2010-2.flv");`

Comment: The video is inside the Jar File(if yes:`use getResource()`),if not use `file:`The video is located at the classpath?at resources folder?at the same package as the class file from which you are passing it to the `Media`?

Comment: @GoXR3Plus I have no issues with the file location, its valid but doesn't play on mac(from jar) and linux(even from url/file ERROR_MEDIA_AUDIO_FORMAT_UNSUPPORTED) but does play on windows. Files itself I open with internal video player and its playing ok on all platforms

Answer (score 0):

Check where the video.mp4 is placed in your jar-file.
Maybe a slash at start will help:

```
Media(getClass().getResource("/video.mp4").toExternalForm());
```

Comment: No you don't need leading slash if your resource placing the same package. As I said the video plays fine from IDE without any slashes but doesn't play from packed JAR WITHOUT errors, it means that the file is found and is not null. When I replace mp4 by flv from oracle one the issue is gone. Thats my problem.